hi, is there a way to download SSL ceritifate files of my firebase project?
i need to use SSL certificate of my webpage as .key , .crt file
more specifically, i need to send a post request including the SSL certificate
it's one of a requirement to use some API of Thai banking service (Kasikorn bank)
i am trying to use their QR generating API and they requires to finish their API exercises
and the last exercise is to send a post request to their endpoint with my SSL certificate included
i tried to create another certificate and use it but it responds an error so my guess is i need to use the one that is actually being used for my web
is there a way to download them ?
thank you
looked up about it but can't find any related posts
(0413 added)
screenshot of the exercise 1/2
screenshot of the exercise 2/2
postman certificate setting 1
postman certificate setting 2
header and error response 

Welcome to Stack Overflow. What are their "exercises" ? a test API ? and what error do you get ?

You already have your certificates, so you don't need to download them. Can you at least provide a link to the API you are referring to?

hi, thanks for the reply.
i added some screen shots.
@gobes , President James K. Polk
